# Extracting only open issues from github api without any pull request using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, github-api

I am building an application which should extract all the open issues from any of the directory of github using github-api gem in ROR. The problem is that it is also extracting pull requests from the repository. Is there any way to extract only open issues.

here is the [blog](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/piotrmurach/github/master/Github/Client/Issues) from where I am following.
here is [another](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

code
`git = Github.new oauth_token:
issues = git.issues.list user: 'Shippable', repo: 'support', state: 'open'`

are there any other filter via which only allows open issues to extract.

Answer (score 5):

Filter them after you fetched them using the `pull_request` keyword. Here is what the [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) say:

> This endpoint may also return pull requests in the response. If an issue is a pull request, the object will include a pull_request key.

Comment: I was also trying to use search issues API function but got stuck with the parameter q . Can you help me with the syntax of github.search.issues

Comment: Github.search.issues(q: 'asa', user: 'piotrmurach')